# Как выводить шрифт Wingdings?

Tags: c++, шрифты

Дело в том, что требуется вывод текста шрифтом "Wingdings".  В Code::Blocks этот шрифт отображается криво. Подскажите, как им нормально пользоваться?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример "кривого" использования. Так будет проще понять как сделать "прямо".

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду часть кода или отображение символов?

Comment: то, что походит под понятие [mcve]